# NW.js native video processing and displaying

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, webgl, video-processing, nwjs

I am working on computer-vision projects and trying to find a way how to build a desktop application with modern UI that will be able to display live video processed by my algorithms. The code that creates video stream and web browser will be on the same machine.

I have a native C++ code that captures video from IP camera, makes some processing of captured frames with drawing results on them. For example - it detects human faces and draws bounding boxes on video frames. Video processing code is quite heavy and can't be translated into javascript.

After that I want to display this frames with boxes on them in Web-based GUI in a desktop application build with NW.js.

The question is how to display processed frames with lowest possible CPU usage overhead?

I can compress each frame into JPG(PNG/BMP...) and send it to `<img>` tag, but this way will take too much CPU, and this is the worst possible solution.

The perfect solution should be sending frame data directly into WebGL texture on GPU by native code, but I cant find a way how to make it.

May be some compromise will be RGB32(24) transfer, but image stream is quite heavy (about 200 MB per second), this is the stream of one 2MP/25fps IP camera. And in a future I want to be able using up to 4 cameras on one PC.

I have an experience with Qt and this task can be solved with Qt, but I really need some HTML5-based GUI with its animations, styles and other features.

My target OS is Windows, but it will be good to have cross-platform solution. And if Windows is a problem - I can use Linux.

Comment: You can use sockets or WebRTC to communicate between your background app and the front end NW.js interface. I have not used C++ for some time but i am sure there are plenty of libs to stream to one of the formats V8 will handle (webM for example) The alternative is to write a plugin for V8 that handles the whole capture/process side of things with a minimal interface for the NW app to control it. You will have direct access to the GPU with that approch.

Comment: @Blindman67, I think, real-time compression of FullHD/25fps into vp8 will need about 8 cores of Intel i7 processor with full load. Do you know any options how to reduce CPU usage on compression?

Comment: forget about vp8,  modern webrtc can work with H264, but you will require strictly baseline profile.  WebRTC is good because it gives small latency, just draw on canvas on top of video element.

Comment: @MaxLapshin, but I still need to spend CPU on compression. h264 is hard to compress, as I know. Is it possible to send raw RGB24/32 and how fast will it be?

Comment: Raw RGB frames is extremely bad idea. 25 fps with FullHD will consume 1 gbit/s.  No browser can sustain such amount of traffic.  You need either to create some combination of browser and your C++ program, either to send video from camera as is and draw your information on top of camera video in browser.